# Как послать JSON в теле HTTP-запроса?

Tags: c#, json, http

Есть класс

```
public struct Message
{
    public string Guid { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
}
```

Этот класс сериализуется в строку:

```
Message message = new Message { Guid = guid, Token = token };
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
```

Как ее передать в тело запроса (предполагается использовать HttpWebRequest)?

Comment: Именно HttpWebRequest нужен?

Comment: Нет, не обязательно. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение просто:

```
body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.ContentLength = body.Length;

using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(body, 0, body.Length);
    stream.Close();
}

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    response.Close();
}
```